# How to get the "Generate Script" of a DB by T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know how to do it using the SQL management for generate script to create a whole DB in SQL.

I need to get the same script but using T-SQL.

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that is a function of the SQL IDE. To replicate that you'd have to do a lot of introspection yourself. Perhaps you have use a third party tool?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken that is a function of the SQL IDE. To replicate that you'd have to do a lot of introspection yourself. Perhaps you have use a third party tool?

To do the introspection you need to look tables and views in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and the `sys` schemas to determine the capabilities of every object and then script them yourself.

There are help stored procedures like `sp_helptext` that you may be able to utilise to make this job easier.